# How to connect Llama-Index Pandas Query Engine with multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, large-language-model, llama-index

As per the documentation of Pandas Query Engine, the code sets only allow for one df to be connected. I would like to connect to multiple dfs. This works on PandasAI through SmartDataLake, but i prefer the descriptive answers given by Pandas Query Engine as a result of cycling the result through the LLM again. Any way to make it work?

Documentation code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./titanic_train.csv") #Only 1 dataframe
instruction_str = (
    "1. Convert the query to executable Python code using Pandas.\n"
    "2. The final line of code should be a Python expression that can be called with the `eval()` function.\n"
    "3. The code should represent a solution to the query.\n"
    "4. PRINT ONLY THE EXPRESSION.\n"
    "5. Do not quote the expression.\n"
)

pandas_prompt_str = (
    "You are working with a pandas dataframe in Python.\n"
    "The name of the dataframe is `df`.\n"
    "This is the result of `print(df.head())`:\n"
    "{df_str}\n\n"
    "Follow these instructions:\n"
    "{instruction_str}\n"
    "Query: {query_str}\n\n"
    "Expression:"
)
response_synthesis_prompt_str = (
    "Given an input question, synthesize a response from the query results.\n"
    "Query: {query_str}\n\n"
    "Pandas Instructions (optional):\n{pandas_instructions}\n\n"
    "Pandas Output: {pandas_output}\n\n"
    "Response: "
)

pandas_prompt = PromptTemplate(pandas_prompt_str).partial_format(
    instruction_str=instruction_str, df_str=df.head(5)
)
```

Trying the below code for multiple data frames

```
instruction_str = (
    "1. Convert the query to executable Python code using Pandas.\n"
    "2. The final line of code should be a Python expression that can be called with the `eval()` function.\n"
    "3. The code should represent a solution to the query.\n"
    "4. PRINT ONLY THE EXPRESSION.\n"
    "5. Do not quote the expression.\n"
)

pandas_prompt_str = (
    "You are working with 3 pandas dataframes in Python.\n"
    "The name of the dataframes is `df1`, 'df2' and 'df3'.\n"
    "This is the result of `print(df1.head())`:\n"
    "{df1_str}\n\n"
    "This is the result of `print(df2.head())`:\n"
    "{df2_str}\n\n"
    "This is the result of `print(df3.head())`:\n"
    "{df3_str}\n\n"
    "Follow these instructions:\n"
    "{instruction_str}\n"
    "Query: {query_str}\n\n"
    "Expression:"
)
response_synthesis_prompt_str = (
    "Given an input question, synthesize a response from the query results.\n"
    "Query: {query_str}\n\n"
    "Pandas Instructions (optional):\n{pandas_instructions}\n\n"
    "Pandas Output: {pandas_output}\n\n"
    "Response: "
)

pandas_prompt1 = PromptTemplate(pandas_prompt_str).partial_format(
    instruction_str=instruction_str, df1_str=df1.head(1)
)
pandas_output_parser1 = PandasInstructionParser(df1)

pandas_prompt2 = PromptTemplate(pandas_prompt_str).partial_format(
    instruction_str=instruction_str, df2_str=df2.head(1)
)
pandas_output_parser2 = PandasInstructionParser(df2)

pandas_prompt3 = PromptTemplate(pandas_prompt_str).partial_format(
    instruction_str=instruction_str, df3_str=df3.head(1)
)
pandas_output_parser3 = PandasInstructionParser(df3)
response_synthesis_prompt = PromptTemplate(response_synthesis_prompt_str)
```

We get the following error

```
ValueError: Module input keys must have exactly one key if dest_key is not specified. Remaining keys: in module: {'df2_str', 'query_str', 'df1_str'}
```